# How to use Makefile to switch to a certain catalogue?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

How can I execute `cd moocs/libs/bin` command using Makefile?

If  I write this command into Makefile, it will return when the subprogram is end. What's worse, `.ONESHELL` doesn't work, either, because of my low version.

Comment: You can't.  This has nothing to do with make: it's a fundamental feature of the operating system that changing the directory in one process doesn't impact the parent (or sibling) processes.  Perhaps if you described what it is you actually want to do at a higher level we would have some advice.

Comment: Why must the operating system obey the rule that changing the directory in one process doesn't impact the parent (or sibling) processes? Is there any necessity?

Comment: I don't quite understand the question.  If you mean, would it be possible to write an operating system that worked that way then sure, anything's possible in software, but it would not be any of the operating systems that exist today.  The issues to be overcome are many and varied.  Basically, you're allowing one process to come in and modify the memory and resources of a different process which brings all sorts of concerns around security, memory safety (what if the process is actually using that directory when someone else changes it?), etc.